# Operations on binomials

Tags: polynomials

I've taken this general rule from Wikipedia( https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_(polynomial) )
${\displaystyle x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}=(x-y)\sum_{k=0}^{n}x^{k}\,y^{n-k}.}$

Applying it to this binomial: $*x^3-y^3* :
*x^3-y^3*=*x^{2+1}-y^{2+1}*=*(x-y)(x+y)^2*=*(x-y)(x^2+2xy+y^2)*$

But according to the article $*x^3-y^3*=*(x-y)(x^{2}+xy+y^{2})*$

My other question is that is there a similar rule for $*x^{n+1}+y^{n+1}*$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you... I needed such a tutorial. I will try to learn as much as possible from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can factor only if $n+1$ is odd:

$$x^{n+1}+y^{n+1} = (x-y)(x^n+x^{n-1}y+...+y^n)$$

Comment: Yes. In my case n+1=3  but thank you for this note

Comment: And you mean x^{n+1}-y^{n+1}

Comment: @ZahraaKhalife on reals when m id odd you can also factorize $x^m+y^m$, EG $x^3+y^3=(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$

Comment: Oh now I realize my confusion , I thought that that summation is the binomial theorem but its not because it lacks the binomial coefficient or the combination.  Haha

Answer (score 0):

Applying the formula from that article to $x^3-y^3$, what you get is $(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2)$. I don't know where you got the equality $x^{2+1}-y^{2+1}=(x-y)(x+y)^2$ from. It is false.